# Hausdorff Property for Preschemes in Mumford's Red Book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f,g: K \to X$ two morphisms between preschemes. In order to "compare" these two morphisms in David Mumford's "Red Book of Varieties and Schemes" there is suggested (see page 118) for a $x \in K$ to say

$f(x)\equiv g(x)$ iff

(1) $f(x)= g(x)$ (as sets) and

(2) the induced maps of residue fields $f^*_x, g^*_x: \kappa(f(x)) \to \kappa(x) $

Here the excerpt:

[image]

My question is why do we need the condition (2)? The main obstruction is what happens with torsion in the induced stalk maps $f^*_x, g^*_x: \mathcal{O}_{X,f(x)} \to \mathcal{O}_{K,x}$.

But when we consider the induced maps $f^*_x, g^*_x: \kappa(f(x)) \to \kappa(x) $ of residue fields then this torsion is killed since by definition $\kappa(x)= \mathcal{O}_{K,x}/m_x$.

So these two maps $f^*_x, g^*_x$ are automatically the canonic inclusions. So they should coinside,right?

Or where is the error in my reasonings making the condition (2) neccessary?

Comment: I mean consider the fact that if $X$ is a scheme over $\mathbb{F}_p$ then its absolute Frobenius $F_X$ s not the identity map of schemes, but is the identity map on underlying spaces. Try to work through that example.

Comment: I would even start with an easier example: what if $K$ and $X$ are the spectrum of a field ?

Comment: @CaptainLama That's obviously an easier example, but I wanted to show somehow that it wasn't a phenomenon of discrete points. Like you might imagine that if $X$ `has sufficiently many points and is sufficiently rich (e.g. a connected positive dimensional smooth variety)' then a sufficiently nice (e.g.  a map over the base field which is finite, flat,...) map is determined by its map on points. This of course is not true.